# how to exclude one instance from SPARQL query result

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I have a query to get some similar instances for a specific instance, which is `owbes:Dies_Irae` instance. This is the query:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?recommendable0 ?predicate0 ?similarity0 } WHERE {
  ?recommendable0 ?predicate0 ?object0.
  owbes:Dies_Irae ?predicate0 ?object0.
  ?predicate0 owbes:hasSimilarityValue ?similarity0.
  ?recommendable0 rdf:type ?someType.
  ?someType rdfs:subClassOf owbes:Recommendable.
}
```

It works fine, I get in the results what I'm supposed to. However, I also get the same instance `owbes:Dies_Irae`. Is there a way to exclude it from the result?

Well, I'm sure there is. I tried to search, I found that there is a filter, I tried to use it, but no succeed.  This is the filter that I apply `FILTER (?recmmendable0 != owbes:Dies_Irae)`

I also tried to check if both of them have the same `rdf:about` but it didn't work.

Here you go the result:

```
<http://www.welovethesemanticweb.com/recommendation-systems#Requiem:_Sequentia>
        recommendation-systems:hasArtist
                "0.4"^^xsd:double .

recommendation-systems:Le_nozze_di_Figaro
        recommendation-systems:hasArtist
                "0.4"^^xsd:double .

recommendation-systems:Dies_Irae
        recommendation-systems:hasArtist
                "0.4"^^xsd:double .
```

as you see, the last instance is the one that I'd like to exclude

Comment: **"I also tried to check if both of them have the same rdf:about but it didn't work."** I think you may misunderstand what **rdf:about** in the RDF/XML serialization means.  It's not a property. It's just one of the several possible ways that the XML serialization uses to identify the IRI being described.  You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118326/differences-between-rdfresource-rdfabout-and-rdfid helpful, as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446778/sparql-query-using-rdfid-returns-no-results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FILTER (?recmmendable0 != owbes:Dies_Irae)
```

You didn't spell `recommendable0` correctly in your filter.  Since the variable isn't used anywhere else, it never has a value, so the **filter** doesn't have anything to compare.

Comment: Thank you, I'm always a miss in English.

Comment: Please can I ask you how can I query the graph that I get from the constract query? I need to make aggregation on the result of the constract graph

Comment: This is a different question, so please open a new one. As a short hint: you would have to use sub SELECT + BIND inside the where part of the CONSTRUCT query. You can't nest CONSTRUCT queries.

Comment: You can't query the **construct**ed graph directly.  You'd have to save it and then run a separate query.  However, you *can* do the aggregation in a subquery, and the construct from the results of that.  As @AKSW says, that's really a separate question, but don't post it just yet;  I think there's already a question like that on here...

Comment: @AniaDavid Yes, have a look at [SPARQL functions in CONSTRUCT/WHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28427219/1281433).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor please can you help me again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273681/how-to-create-aggregation-on-a-graph-from-construct I value that a lot

Comment: Would it be possible to do this with MINUS instead of FILTER?