# SPARQL apply MAX on a value of aggregation

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I have this query:

```
prefix : <http://test.example/> 

select  ?anotherUser  (COUNT(?anotherItem) as ?countOfSharedLikedItems) 
WHERE 
{
   values ?user {:ania}.
   ?anotherUser :likes ?anotherItem.

   filter (?anotherUser != ?user)
   filter exists {?user :likes ?anotherItem}
}
group by ?anotherUser
order by desc(?countOfSharedLikedItems)
```

That runs on this data:

```
@prefix : <http://test.example/> .

:alice :likes :beethoven.
:alice :likes :verdi.
:sofia :likes :beethoven.
:sofia :likes :verdi.
:sofia :likes :rossini.
:sofia :likes :mozart.
:ania :likes :verdi.
:ania :likes :beethoven.
:ania :likes :david.
:david :likes :ania.
:david :likes :beethoven.
:david :likes :verdi.
:antonino :likes :verdi.
:antonino :likes :mozart.
:weirdo :likes :katyperry.
:beethoven a :recommendable.
:verdi a :recommendable.
:rossini a :recommendable.
:katyperry a :recommendable.
:mozart a :recommendable.
```

It is working fine, I'm making aggregation and bound the value to a variable called `countOfSharedLikedItems`. Now I want to have the maximum value of that parameter, I tried this:

```
prefix : <http://test.example/> 

select  
   ?anotherUser 
   (MAX(?countOfSharedLikedItems) as ?max) 
   (COUNT(?anotherItem) as ?countOfSharedLikedItems)  
WHERE 
{
   values ?user { :ania }.
   ?anotherUser :likes ?anotherItem.

   filter (?anotherUser != ?user)
   filter exists { ?user :likes ?anotherItem }
}
group by ?anotherUser
order by desc(?countOfSharedLikedItems)
```

But the result for the variable `max` is always empty.

What wrong did I do?

**Hint** I do need to have the three variables in the output which are `anotherUser`, `countOfSharedLikedItems`, and `max`. Otherwise, I would have just make an outer select and I could get the max, but I need the three of them, that's why I am asking because i didn't could do it myself

#### Update 1

I tried this **SILLY** solution, it works, but it is obviously so silly

```
prefix : <http://test.example/> 
select ?anotherUser ?countOfSharedLikedItems ?maxSharedLikedItems 
WHERE {
{
   select  
      ?anotherUser  
      (COUNT(?anotherItem) as ?countOfSharedLikedItems)  
   WHERE 
   {     
      values ?user { :ania }.
      ?anotherUser :likes ?anotherItem.

      filter (?anotherUser != ?user)
      filter exists { ?user :likes ?anotherItem }
   }
   group by ?anotherUser
   order by desc(?countOfSharedLikedItems)
}
{
   select (MAX(?countOfSharedLikedItems) as ?maxSharedLikedItems) 
   WHERE 
   {
       select  
          ?anotherUser  
          (COUNT(?anotherItem) as ?countOfSharedLikedItems)  
       WHERE 
       {
          values ?user { :ania }.
          ?anotherUser :likes ?anotherItem.

          filter (?anotherUser != ?user)
          filter exists { ?user :likes ?anotherItem }
       }
       group by ?anotherUser
   }
}
}
```

could you check please and suggest another better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your outermost query has a fatal issue in these parts:

```
select  
   (MAX(?countOfSharedLikedItems) as ?max) 
   (COUNT(?anotherItem) as ?countOfSharedLikedItems)  
WHERE { ... }
group by ?anotherUser
```

You need to fully understand what **group by** does.  The triples in the **where** part provide a bunch of result rows.  E.g., in a query like

```
select * where {
  ?s ?p ?o 
}
```

the result is a bunch of rows, each of which has a value for each of the variables.  When you add a **group by** clause, you're saying that you want to partition those rows up into a bunch of sets.  E.g., if the results had been

```
s1 p1 o1
s1 p2 o2
s2 p1 o2
s2 p1 o3
s3 p1 o2
```

and you grouped by ?s, then you partition those results into something like this:

```
s1
   [ p1 o1 ]
   [ p2 o2 ]

s2 
   [ p1 o2 ]
   [ p1 o3 ]

s3 
   [ p1 o2 ]
```

For each unique s value, you still have a bunch of rows, each of which provides a p and an o value.  The aggregation functions operate over those bunches.  So when you do something like

```
select ?s (max(?o) as ?oMax) where {
  ?s ?p ?o
}
group by ?s
```

the **max** aggregate gets to work on each of the bunches, i.e., on [o1, o2], [o2, o3], and [o2], and produces a single value from each one.  So something like

```
select  
   (count(?o) as ?numO)
   (max(?numO) as ?oMax) 
group by ?s
```

doesn't make sense.  When you group by ?s, the count operates within each bunch, and there are some values, so you can count them.  But **max** also tries to operate within each bunch, but the bunches don't have any binding of ?numO to look at.  And even if you could use the value from **count(?o)**, there'd only be *one per bunch*, so **max** would just be returning that value.

Comment: it sounds like I didn't explain more my question, yes I do need the max to be on *each* bunch that results in the group by (then I will divide the count for each person agains the max). However, now in another query, I need the max on the all. Anyway, I am still stuck in this question, i want to have the max of the count. Can I please give you the data and what I want to achieve and my current query (which is almost done), except this part and you help me ? (i can make a new quesiton if you wish, i really appreciate it and i am stuck in three days here)

Comment: Mainly [this is my result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa9QU.png) and I just want to divide the `similarityWithRating` variable by the maximum number of `countOfItemsUsedInDeterminingTheSimilarities` I can give you any information you want

Comment: I am thinking of possible solutions, do you think I can make construct and then save the resulted graph in a name and then query that name ? (All this during one SPARQL query), I 99% know the answer is no, but I am just validating with you

Comment: @ania the aggregate functions operate all the values in a group and return one value per group.  If COUNT over the values in a group you get a single value per group.  You're trying to then MAXimize over that *single* value, but that value isn't in scope, and even if it were, there'd only be a single value to maximize over, which isn't interesting.  Can you edit your question to show the results that you want to get?

Comment: Okay I will show you, but in a new question, because this question is too long

Comment: @ania you've already shown the data here and an attempted result.  To show the results you *want* shouldn't be adding all that much, and even if it makes the question longer, it's really a part of *this* question. If you pay or as a new one, it would probably be closed as a duplicate of this one. Edit *this* question, please; dint create a new one.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't read your comment :(, i already posted a new question, really long one explaining every every thing, could you have a look at least please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577896/sparql-full-aggregation-on-a-group-aggregation

Comment: Kindly no help there please ?

Comment: @AniaDavid I'll take a look when I have time;  I still have to do my day job, after all.

Comment: Yeah!, thanks in advance, bty enjoy your Rome, it is amazing city. I've been there last month. It is astonishing

Comment: @AniaDavid I think you may be confused about Rome.  I'm in [Rome, New York, USA](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rome,+NY+13440/@43.201687,-75.6149553,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x89d9115ef13e4799:0xc2320966c2e1daad).  It's nice, and has some American history, but you may be thinking of Rome, Italy.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I though Roma, the capital of Italia. I'm sure your city is beautiful too. sorry again, it is just i saw your profile and Rome for me is the heaven. Highly strongly recommended to visit if u haven't yet :)